# How can I fetch data where my condition uses data from another row of same table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table:

```
| id | created_at                 | updated_at                 | visited_page | visited_date | user_id |
+----+----------------------------+----------------------------+-------------------+--------------+-----
|  1 | 2020-12-28 18:09:40.243560 | 2020-12-28 18:09:40.244170 |            1 | 2020-12-28   |   78557 |
|  2 | 2020-12-28 18:10:41.290824 | 2020-12-28 18:10:41.291217 |            1 | 2020-12-29   |   78557 |
|  3 | 2020-12-28 18:19:36.948853 | 2020-12-28 18:19:36.949289 |            3 | 2020-12-29   |   78557 |
+----+----------------------------+----------------------------+-------------------+--------------+-----
```

Here I want to fetch `user_ids` where the `updated_at` difference between two different pages visited by the same user is greater than 6 minutes on a particular date (in above tables case date = 2020-12-29).

Please explain how this query will look in SQL?

Comment: Hi Arpit, you should provide some code and what you've tried to achieve your goal, not only what you want, expecting that S.O users make your work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

didn't test , but something like this should be the naswer :

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.user_id
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table1 t2
    ON t1.visiated_date = t2.visited_date
    AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, t1.updated_at, t2.updated_at) > 6
    AND t1.visited_page <> t2.visited_page
    AND t1.date = 2020-12-29
```